# How to fix Java.security.AcessControlExpection

Tags: java, swing, sockets, applet, accesscontrolexception

I'm trying to execute my Java project on Delay analysis on Multihop and wireless networks so I'm getting this error.

See the pic for more detail: http://tinypic.com/r/245locn/8

Comment: Post a minimum executable code that reproduces your problem. Also, avoid "please", "asap", "thank you", etc. StackOverflow is a site to post your question and get good answers, you don't need to beg for help.

Comment: 1) Don't post an image of text!  To copy text from the Windows CLI, right click to produce the context menu, select Mark, arrow left/right/up or down while holding 'shift' to select the text, then hit 'enter' 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 3) Note that the only person that cares about the urgency of your task is ***you.***  That and most of us prefer to help people with better time management skills (e.g. people who do not put 'ASAP').

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: And make some sort of an effort to spell your title correctly. If you want serious attention, that is.

Answer (score 1):

The applet viewer will not allow connections to foreign hosts.

An applet in a web page that connects to foreign hosts needs to:

1. Be digitally signed by you.
2. Declare `all-permissions` in the manifest.
3. Be trusted by the end user. (They click 'OK' when prompted.)